# Finite state machines how to implement minimum and maximum hits

Tags: algorithm, fsm

I'm trying to implement a fsm and it's going fine. I can enter strings and see if they are valid and all that kind of stuff.

However regular expressions (which are fsms) have this feature where you can specify how many times a certain character may occur for example a{2,4} would accept "aa" and "aaa" but not "aaaaa" and "a"

I can imagine having a counter on edges that count how many times they have been hit and use this to deny any characters after the counter has hit a certain number but you can't implement minimum this way because it would always block the first character (unless minimum is 0).

Does anyone know a way to implement this feature?
it also has to work for really big numbers like a{1,99999999999}

Comment: Care to explain what is the relation between finite state machines and regular expressions and show us some code?

Comment: @andrea regular expressions are finite state machines

Comment: Oh now it's clear... I appreciate that I might not be an expert on the subject, but if you care to explain in a clearer way the problem you might help others understand the subject and attract the attention and help of more people.

Comment: Isn't `aaa?a?` equivalent?

Comment: For finite {n,m} you can get away by "exploding" the FSM: just stack it onto itself. again and again. For infinite FSM's you'll need a stack to remember the guessed states.

Comment: @ erick the regex aaa?a? means you may have 3a's and you may add another and no it would block certain strings that a{2,4} would alllow like "aa"

Comment: @joop maybe you're onto something but i'm not following

Comment: @PaulBoon no, `aaa?a?` matches at least two `a`, followed optionally by one or two others. It matches "aa", "aaa", and "aaaa" and nothing else.

Comment: you're right i thought the first 3a's were grouped but they are not.
however it doesnt solve the problem when the numbers are getting really big like a{1,9999999} it would also require that many states and that cant be a good solution

Comment: The point being that if you implement `aaa?a?` you have implemented `a{2,4}`. The latter notation is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom you're right but it's not a solution. with big numbers it would requrie to many states

Comment: Actually that's the only solution, if you want to implement it with only finite state machines.

Comment: @HenryLee how do you implement it using other things?

Comment: Other things include the Turing machines, shouldn't that be very easy to implement even in C language?

Comment: What my point was, if you want to use only finite state machine for a regex includes `{1, 100}`, then you have to create a hundred states for it. Otherwise, everything is easy.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, this kind of constraint cannot be implemented dynamically in a finite state machine; parts of the FSM would have to be statically expanded. In your example, for `a{2,3}` three different separate FSMs would have to be built, one accepting `aa`, the second one accepting `aaa` and the third one accepting `aaaa`; these would then have to be made alternatives in the final FSM via some empty transitions. The reason for this is the fact that the FSM itself does not store the path by which its current state was reached, which means that a paremeterized form of the pattern `a{i,j}` cannot be checked.

Comment: does this mean that if i make a regular expression like a{1,999999999} than that many fsms are made? sounds ulikely to me

Comment: I share your skepticism here; However I'm not sure if implementations of regular expression engines use FSMs alone. If I'm not mistaken, the notion of _regular expressions_ typically presented in introductory courses of computer science does not _exactly_ match the _regular expressions_ which are typically implemented.

Comment: i feel like there is a more elegent solution than just makig a whole lot of fsms

Comment: Might be, but perhaps not with an FSM. Are you familiar with the so-called pumping lemma for FSMs?

Comment: yeah i think you're right but than the question remains how is it done? andi haven't heard of pumping lemma

Comment: I dont't know how it's done. I find it unfortunate that the notions don't quite match. Basically, the pumping lemma states the following: If an FSM accepts a word longer than its number of states, there must be a cycle in the FSM on the path which accepts the input. Consequently, other words must be accepted, namely the ones where the cycle is repeated at will or completely removed. A more comprehensive description can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)